# How to check if any of the items in the generic list is null or 0

Tags: c#

I am using the below line of code to check if any of the items in the generic lists is empty
or 0

```
if (Region.Dept.College[index].Student.Any(
    c => c.Age=null || 
        c.Name !=null || 
        c.code!=null || 
        c.Fees!=null || 
        c.Gender!=null || 
        c.M1!=null || 
        c.grade!= null || 
        c.caste!= null || 
        c.castespecified!= null || 
        c.GradeLevel!= null || 
        c.Gradelevelspecified!= null || 
        c.FeePercent!= 0 || 
        c.FeePercentSpecified != null || 
        c.StudentRegistrationID!= null)
```

But even if all the items are empty it still enters the if loop, which is incorrect. please help me to correct this.

Variables are sample

Comment: `c.Age = null` <-- sure?

Comment: This isn't checking if an item in the list is null or 0. This checking if an item in the list has a property which is null or 0 (depending on what that property is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check whether any student has a any null property (i.e. `c => c.Age==null || c.Name ==null || ..` )  and if so **not** enter the loop, so it should be:

```
if(!Region.Dept.College[index].Student.Any(condition))
{
  //loop code here, all students valid
}
```

Currently you are testing for the opposite - you are testing whether *any* student is valid, not if all are valid (which is equivalent to not any invalid). Also examine your null checks - depending on the data type you need different checks, i.e. `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` for strings etc.

Also I assume `c.Age=null` was just a typo, otherwise wouldn't compile.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the code, as written, wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

<del>Looks like you're including `null` ages by mistake</del>

**EDIT:** Though, I might offload that validation to a method returning a boolean then just reference the method in the `If`. 
To keep it clean, make a function which takes the object as a parameter, then in that function do all this validation and return a boolean.
Something like `AllValuesEmpty`
Then, your predicate should just be the result of that function.

This is better practice because later if you want to add something to the object or change how you validate whether or not it's empty you can just change one method rather than having to search for long, complicated `If` conditions.

**EDIT2:** Also note that C# makes a distinction between `NULL` values any *empty* values. Where `NULL` indicates "there is no reference to anything which could be used to resolve this" and *empty* indicates "there is space referenced for this, but there's nothing useful stored there"

Perhaps your properties are initialized with default values in the constructor of your object. Perhaps they're *empty* but not `NULL`

Answer (score 2):

```
c => c.Age=null
```

Should be

```
c => c.Age==null
```

You're basically assigning Age to null for all the students.

Comment: You are right with `=` versus `==` but I think she actually means `!=`

Comment: Sorry for the typo error on the forum it is c.Age!=null , it does not help

Comment: @Matthew, @Janet: Or possibly even `c.Age > 0`, depending on the actual type of `Age`.

Answer (score 1):

You have `c => c.Age=null || ...`—was that supposed to be `c => c.Age != 0` ?

Answer (score 0):

To identify which check is failing, perform them one by one with a breakpoint right after.